I am a dual citizen of the Philippines and the US. Can I return to the US after staying in the Philippines for more than 3 years?
I am a dual citizen of the Philippines and the US. Can I return to the US after staying in the Philippines for more than 3 years?

Yes, you're a citizen of the US, so it doesn't matter how long you spend out of the country, they'll still admit you.

I hope you've been filing US tax returns while you were away, if your income was high enough for this to be necessary. But I don't think it would prevent you from being admitted to the US.

Do you have some reason to think that you wouldn't be able to?

Do you have a valid passport? If not you’ll need to get a new one. Other than that, as others wrote, a US citizen is nearly by definition allowed to travel to and enter the US.


Can I return to the US after staying in the Philippines for more than 3 years?

Yes. As long as you are a US citizen, you cannot be denied entry into the US.
However, you will need a valid US passport to board a US-bound plane. Without it, the airline will deny you boarding.

If the questioner has a Philippines passport but no US passport, couldn't they use the Philippines passport to board the plane, then their US citizenship to enter the country? Or can US citizens now be denied entry simply because they don't have a (US) passport? Ofc it might not be much harder to get the US passport than it is to get the visa they'd need to board with the Philippines passport.

Oh, ofc, the US won't issue that visa because they'll ask for all your citizenships in the application. Lying to obtain a visa, even one you don't really need, feels like an extremely bad idea.

If you are a citizen of the USA and can prove that, you can go to the USA and will be admitted, regardless of whether you have been there before.
This is basically the same with citizens of all countries, although not all accept their citizens having a second (or more) citizenship.

China, for example does not recognize that someone who is a Chinese citizen could also have another nationality.
